# Device troubleshooting tools

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have rather generic question. Have a semi-large fleet of IoT devices (1000+) and using IoT Edge. I need a way to troubleshoot those devices effectively. So far I've been using simple ssh to log in and examine misbehaving devices, but I am wondering if someone can recommend a tool that can be used instead. Best if I can see a list of devices and use some remote terminal functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking for your custom module runtime status, you can get that information by inspecting the `edgeAgent` module twin of the device. The `edgeAgent` module twin includes the `desired` and `reported` section properties. By comparing the reported property values against the desired values, you can determine discrepancies and identify disconnections that can help you troubleshoot issues. The `edgeAgent` module twin can be accessed easily through Azure portal, SDKs or through Azure CLI. Refer the article [Monitor module twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-monitor-module-twins?view=iotedge-1.4#monitor-iot-edge-agent-module-twin) for more details on this.

There is an out of the box module named **Metrics Collector Module** which can be added to IoT Edge device to onboard additional monitoring of IoT Edge devices through Azure portal. This custom module processes the data generated by the `edgeAgent` and presents meaningful insights such as how long a module has been running correctly, or the amount of RAM and percent of CPU being used on the device.  It presents a nice UI where you can track each device modules on the portal. Refer the below image for reference.

[image]

Refer the article [Tutorial: Monitor IoT Edge devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-monitor-with-workbooks?view=iotedge-1.4) for more details.

Hope this helps! If you are looking to monitor a specific scenario or use case, please update the question to include more details.